# How do I make Mantaflow fire appear less blocky and more realistic?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, fire

The other objects in the scene are set to fire and smoke with sampling sub steps set to 2 and initial velocity turned on, but other than that, they are at the default settings. I'm also using the cycles engine. Here are the settings of the smoke domain:
[[image: Smoke Domain Settings]

[image: Smoke Domain Settings]

[image: Smoke Domain Settings]

[image: Smoke Domain Settings]

[image: Smoke Domain Settings]

[image: Minecraft Fire]

[image: Scaled Down Smoke Domain @ 140 Resolution Divisions]

Comment: The size of the simulation cells are determined by the Resolution settings of the domain. You don’t show how large your domain is in relation to the fire. Try shrinking your domain or significantly increasing the resolution (double the resolution will give half the cell dimensions (but 8 times the effort to simulate)).

Comment: I find with particles, a focus on resolution (like Resolution Divisions) is important.   What is the original object sourcing the flames prior to simulation?  It looks like a series of cubes.

Comment: Two planes and an Icosphere at as the source of fire and smoke. I just added more resolution divisions, but for some reason it appears more blocky. Should I smooth out the Icosphere?